# Magento SOAP v1 - updating product by SKU

Tags: magento-1.9, product, soap

I want to update product by it's  SKU. I've found that it is possible to do with following code:

```
$client->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product.update', array($product_sku, array(
            'stock' => $stock)), null, 'SKU');
```

And... it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you cannot pass the SKU as an argument of `catalog_product.update`:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.update.html

I suggest you use the `catalog_product.info` which accepts the SKU as an argument to retrieve the product ID then use the `catalog_product.update` function with the product ID you retrieved :

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but tt says that the last argument: identyfierType - Defines whether the product ID or SKU is passed in the 'product' parameter.

Comment: You're right, however it is not specified the same way as specified on the info page. Not sure on this one, wait for more people who have tested that.